# Thunderbolt 3 not working with DELL XPS 13-9360 and ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, multiple-monitors, dell

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Kernel: kernel 4.4.0-169-generic
Product Name: Del XPS 13-9360, Dell 470-ABRY DA200 Adapter
Firmware: 0.2.12.0
BIOS: Version 2.12.0, Thunderbolt BIOS Security Level none

**The Problem**

If I connect an external monitor via thunderbolt 3 port, the monitor gets power, but says "No signal". The display on the laptop shows short sequences of a black screen every 10 secs or so. On Windows (dual-boot) it works fine.

```
    dmesg | grep thunderbolt
```

shows no output.

```
    lspci -nn | grep thunderbolt
```

shows no output.

```
    lsmod | grep thunderbolt
```

shows no output.

```
    fwupdmr get-devices
```

shows:
...
Unknown Device
  Guid:                 3ec3df3a-2290-56e5-9d2f-eda62e9ab50b
  DeviceID:             ro__sys_devices_pci0000_00_0000_00_02_0
  Plugin:               udev
  Flags:                internal|locked
  DeviceVendor:         Intel Corporation
  Created:              2019-11-17

**The Questions**

Is the Unknown Device the problem?
Is there a way to log errors while the monitor is connected to the laptop?
Why can't the kernel find or create the thunderbolt 3 module?
Is there a way to manually load the thunderbolt 3 module into the kernel?
I am grateful for your input, but keep in mind that I just have basic knowledge on ubuntu.

Comment: I'm using kernel 4.14.153 with my Ubuntu 16.04 and it works well for Thunderbolt 3. You can try a new kernel too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I read your post on manually installing linux kernels and will give this a try.

Comment: @AlexanderFrank You should add the `-i` flag to grep for most of those checks. The `lspci` command, for example, outputs "Thunderbolt", which would be skipped with your command above.